# Connect to Sonic ESB using Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, esb

Can Camel connect to Sonic ESB?
I could not find any camel-sonic integration specific example. That's why I am confused if it is possible at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connecting ESBs in general does not require specific transports since ESBs are connectivity software packages. You could probably pick and choose which transport fits you best and get started.

Comment: You make perfect sense Petter!

Answer (score 3):

I had a look at Sonic ESB as I have never worked with it. However I can see a couple of ways you can integrate camel routes with the ESB.

1. *Web services:* If you are hosting web services on the Sonice ESB camel is more than capable of calling these web services from a camel route.
2. *JMS:* If Sonic ESB can host a JMS route (I am sure it can but could be wrong) you can just send JMS messages from your Camel route to the JMS queues hosted by Sonic ESB.
3. *The JBI Component:* Some ESB's such as Apache ServiceMix and OpenESB is based on the JBI standard. IF Sonic ESB uses this standard you should be able to send JBI messages directly to the Sonic ESB system.

Hope this gives you some pointers to look at.